# How to run F# Silverlight Library project holding xUnit.net Contrib based unit tests?

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, f#, xunit.net, xunit

I am unaware of any project templates for F# Silverlight 4 unit tests (I searched Online for templates through Add Project), so I am using the standard F# Silverlight Library project to hold my unit tests (which are just file links to the main unit test project files). I am using  [xUnit.net Contrib for Silverlight](http://xunitcontrib.codeplex.com/releases/view/62697). So everything compiles but I don't know how to run the tests! TestDriven.NET works for my normal unit test project but not this Silverlight unit test project. I tried to use the normal xUnit GUI runner but that doesn't work either. Any ideas?

**Update**

The xUnit.net Contrib folks recommended using [Statlight](http://statlight.codeplex.com/) as a standalone console runner. After adding System.Xml.Linq to my test project with Copy Local=true (my project doesn't need it but Statlight does) I was able to run the executable pointing at my test assembly without any errors except it was unable to find any tests.

I tried lots of things to try and allow the tests to be found. I gave explicit namespaces to my test modules. I tried test method names without spaces. I tried types with instance members instead of functions in modules. I even tried the explicit `--MethodsToTest` flag. Nothing works.

I'm not sure if this would be a problem with Statlight or xUnit.net Contrib.

Please note that I am merely trying to test a plain library which can be consumed by Silverlight projects and doesn't actually use any Silverlight features (indeed, I don't have any prior Silverlight experience!).

**Update 2**

I was able to add the normal xunit assembly to my project through NuGet (which "forces" it in despite not being built for Silverlight) and then run the tests successfully using Testdriven.NET. But I'm not sure if this is "cheating". Perhaps not because my tests are still compiled against the Silverlight version of my library...?

**Update 3**

While I still haven't had any luck with a "legit" xunit solution, I was able to get Statlight to run some NUnit tests. Except, it only recognizes tests on instance methods of a class, it doesn't recognize tests on functions of a module (while it can handle these just fine in a normal project). Bummer. (I filed an [issue](http://statlight.codeplex.com/workitem/14088) with Statlight)

**Update 4**

I've figured out a super hacky but workable solution to my problem, still looking for something better though. All of my tests are Xunit tests (file links to the non-Silverlight test project) written as functions in modules but I can't get Statlight to find any of the tests. However, I was able to get Statlight to run NUnit tests which are written in the traditional fashion as instance members of a type. Thus I was able to whip up the following single NUnit test which finds all the Xunit tests in the assembly and invokes them (so I can only see one failing test as a time, but other than that it does work well):

```
namespace SilverlightTesting

open Xunit
open NUnit.Framework

[<TestFixture>]
type TestRunner() =
    let isFact (attr:obj) =
        match attr with
        | :? Xunit.FactAttribute as attr when attr.Skip = null -> true
        | _ -> false

    [<Test>]
    member this.Run () =
        let assm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
        let tys = assm.GetTypes()
        let mutable count = 0
        for ty in tys do
            let methods = ty.GetMethods()
            for mi in methods do
                let attrs = mi.GetCustomAttributes(false)
                if attrs |> Array.exists isFact then
                    printf "running test `%s`..." mi.Name
                    mi.Invoke(null,null) |> ignore
                    printfn "passed"
                    count <- count + 1
        printfn "All %i tests passed." count
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used [lighthouse](http://lighthouse.codeplex.com/) sucessfully in the past, but I don't know if it works with xUnit I used it with mstest. Currently working with AGUnit which is statlight based resharper plugin combined with nunit, though it has difficulty with [dll only silverlight](http://agunit.codeplex.com/discussions/266737) projects--they work if you make it into a xap file.

Comment: Thanks for the tips -- I'm having trouble out of the gate with lighthouse but I'm going to keep working on it. If needed, I may be able to do some trickery to run my tests as NUnit tests, but probably not MSTest since it doesn't support module functions as test methods I believe (and I have ~450 tests which wouldn't be practical or desirable to convert). Any thoughts on my "Update 2"?

Comment: In regards to update 2, I'm skeptical on the cheating, it seems to me that test driven shouldn't be running silverlight tests if that's not a feature, and if it is it's not running them against the silverlight base libraries. Also my unit tests with the member syntax, i didn't even think about the let syntax, that could be the problem with statlight that you are having it's reflection to find the test probably isn't matching up with what the F# compilier is making with let.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm going to keep trying for a "legit" solution. I do think it is running against the Silverlight base libraries but not against the Silverlight runtime which I imagine could have different characteristics and not just be a matter of binary compatibility.

Comment: FYI - you were definitely right that the cheat approach was not sufficient, with my Update 4 working hack I've already seen Silverlight specific failures which I did not see with the cheat.

Comment: fyi Unquote support for Silverlight 4 is now complete and available from download via NuGet and the project's Download page. See http://code.google.com/p/unquote/wiki/SilverlightSupport?ts=1313704895&updated=SilverlightSupport for info. Note that both the standard .NET 4.0 build and the Silverlight 4 build are packaged in the same NuGet package.